# Is dirigible cluster ballooning feasible?

Tags: balloon, lighter-than-air

Has steerable [cluster ballooning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_ballooning) with a propeller and fins/stabilizers of some sort ever been attempted? If not, would it really make sense at all, and what would the challenges be, as compared to a normal airship?
Since to be steerable the aircraft needs to have a somewhat stable shape, would perhaps fixing the multiple balloons with some bands or by some other mechanism help at all, given their stretchiness? Would the passing of air in between balloons affect flight characteristics negatively?
Maybe would it make more sense to cover the cluster of balloons with an outer, non gas-tight envelope? But that already reminds me of rigid airships, and the gas bags there were for some reason made not out of rubber but out of cow gut - I'm also wondering if rubber was  unsuitable for such an application, or if cow gut was more economical back then.

Comment: In the wide open experimental realm of the examples you cite, anything is feasible.  This isn’t a good question though, it’s more of an invitation to random musings…

Comment: The rules here (and everywhere on SE) call for a single question per post. Sometimes you can get away with 2 or 3 _closely_ related questions. I count 5 question marks, and you end up talking about "cow gut" which seems _quite_ unrelated to feasibility of cluster ballooning, but might make it if it was in its own question.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in the title rather than the body - no it is not feasible in most cases.

The usefulness of a powered lighter than air craft hinges greatly on the useful payload VS drag. For a given lifting gas you want the minium amount of balloon skin holding it in, for a cluster balloon you end up with a fairly poor ratio of skin area to internal volume.

You also have issues with the balloons touching and rubbing together which is not good for extended flight, and a cluster of spheres will tend to make for a higher frontal area (higher drag) than a conventional design in a neat row with a aerodynamic shell.

There are cases where the ratio of needed balloon size to structure is low enough that it makes sense to have a beam with balloons spaced along them, such as  under water or non earthlike atmospheres but on earth, with the current atmosphere this does not make sense.

As you note, Zepplin style rigid designs ARE sort of cluster balloons since as size increases there are issues with 'sloshing' of the gas similar to [water hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer) that require increasing skin strength to manage, and also instability if too much of the lifting gas is free to move along the length of the craft so they are technically a row of balloons flying in very close formation, but constrained for stability and reduced wear.